# Need help to animate a moving line with onDraw() - JAVA

Tags: java, android, animation, graphics, ondraw

I made a line via the `drawLine` method that starts from the bottom and goes to half the screen size. 
So far so good. Now I wanted to "tilt" the line to the left or right when the screen is pressed.
Something like this in the picture:

[image]

And when pressed again have it tilt back to the other side and so on.
The problem I have now is that when I tilt the line, its "trail" is visible, because I call the `drawLine` method multiple times.

This is my code:

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private static final String TAG = MainGamePanel.class.getSimpleName();

private MainThread thread;
private Paint paint;
private GameLine gameLine;

public MainGamePanel(Context context){
    super(context);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    setFocusable(true);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(50);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    gameLine = new GameLine(getWidth()/2,getHeight(),getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2,paint);

    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
    gameLine = new GameLine(getWidth()/2,getHeight(),getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2,paint);

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    ...}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        gameLine.setTapped(true);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void render(Canvas canvas) {
    gameLine.drawTheLine(canvas);
}
public void update(){
    gameLine.update();
}}

public class MainThread extends Thread {

private boolean running;
private MainGamePanel gamePanel;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gamePanel){
    super();
    this.gamePanel=gamePanel;
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
}

public void setRunning(boolean running){
    this.running = running;
}
@Override
public void run(){
    Canvas canvas;
    while (running){
        canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder){
                this.gamePanel.update();
                this.gamePanel.render(canvas);
            }
        }finally {
            if(canvas != null){
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}}
public class GameLine {

private float startX;
private float startY;
private float stopX;
private float stopY;
private Paint paint;
private boolean tapped = false;


public GameLine(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Paint paint) {
    Normal Constructor
}
public boolean getTapped(){
    return tapped;
}
public void setTapped(boolean tapped){
    this.tapped = tapped;
}
public void update(){
    if(tapped){
        this.stopX -=1;
    }
}
public void drawTheLine(Canvas canvas){

    canvas.drawLine(startX, startY,stopX, stopY,paint);
}}
```

I'm looking for any ideas. Did I attempt this the wrong way?
How can I make the trail invisible?
I'm grateful for any help. Thank you.

Comment: @NaN New users with < 10 rep are not allowed to post images directly in their questions, so for them a link is the preferred way to include an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to eliminate the trail, you need to throw away the old canvas (to be more precise the old bitmap) and create a new one.
In your example i would suggest:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    Canvas canvas;
    while (running){
        canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder){
                this.gamePanel.update();
                canvas = gameLine.drawTheLine();
            }
        }finally {
            if(canvas != null){
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public Canvas drawTheLine(){
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.drawLine(startX, startY,stopX, stopY,paint);
    return canvas;
}
```